# Custom form in email on Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forms

Is there a way for me to create a form in an email that can be used for booking items (eg. rooms, vehicles, tools, etc.) on Outlook 2007? So it should allow the receiver to input start date/time, and end date/time, and also some other additional details.

So my scenario is this: A customer will contact me asking me to book an item. Sometimes they give me incomplete details or no details at all and I want to save time by just sending them an email that contains a form that they can fill out. It's also good for record-keeping.

In the future, I am also thinking of making a worksheet on Excel or a connection to a database for the entries I get, but for now, I just want to keep it simple, but not limited to future developments. By "simple", I mean just forms in emails so I can look at them so I can record them manually in the system.

Comment: As it stands your question is way too broad. Start by googling "outlook forms" and come back when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) ... you take the survey data then it will automatically save it to Google Sheets. You can then install a [ODBC driver](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b4717628-a718-45b0-9ff7-9bdbb29f9f44) that will take your Google Sheets and load it into Excel.

Comment: I would really like to stick with Outlook.

Comment: More work for you because you have to save Outlook form data to Excel while what I suggest is automated. I don't have suggestions for Outlook forms. Maybe someone else can chime in...